# A basic doubt on derivatives and tangents

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to prove that the derivative of a function at a point is actually the slope of the tangent of the curve at that point (and vice-versa). Now, what definition of tangent should I use ? A line which touches the curve at exactly one point is not correct I think.

Comment: You are correct that defining a tangent as a line touching a curve at one point is incorrect: that would make any two nonparallel lines tangent. Unfortunately, the usual definition of a tangent to a curve at a point is just "the line passing through the point with slope equal to the derivative of the curve," which leaves very little for you to prove.

Comment: A tangent is usually defined in the same way the derivative is, with the instantaneous slope.

Comment: $\large y = 1$ is a line which is tangent to $\large y = \sin\left(x\right)$ at 'infinite' points.

Comment: @WilliamBallinger is correct... the idea that I use is that the tangent to the curve at $x=a$ is the best line approximation to the curve at $x=a$.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a derivative at some point means that the function is "locally" almost linear at that point.  This is a very fundamental concept that tends to get buried in all the fuss of learning to compute derivatives.

So we could think of the "tangent" line as being the line the function would be if it really were linear in some small neighborhood of the point, instead of "almost linear".  Continuing to think geometrically, we are constructing that tangent line by using secant lines, which are clearly defined, through intervals that are smaller and smaller around the point.

Much of the power of the derivative is, precisely, in this approximation to linearity.  Anything you might want to prove about functions is usually quite easy if the function is linear.  Then when it is not linear, the derivative (if it exists) allows us to say -- well, it is almost linear, at least in a small enough neighborhood of this point.  And a surprising number of proofs that work for linear functions can be extended to almost linear functions.

Comment: Suppose $f(t)$ is differentiable at $x$. This implies $f(t)-f(x)=f'(x)(t-x) + u(t)(t-x)$ where $u(t) -> 0$ as $t->x$. So, when $t -> x$ f is linear function of $t$ with slope $f'(x)$. This line is called tangent line. This is the way tangent is defined. Is this observation correct ?

Comment: @user96000 Bingo.

Comment: @user96000  Yes, if I may rephrase what you are saying:  if x is a specific point, t is a variable and f'(x) exists then in a neighborhood of x f(t) = f(x) +f'(x)(t-x) + R(t) where R(t)/(t-x) $\rightarrow$ 0.  This is an explicit way to say that f(t) is  nearly linear in the neighborhood of x, except for a small error function R(t).

Answer (score 0):

There are functions for which a tangent exists, but which are not differentiable.  Consider $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$.  So you the existence of a tangent line does not imply differentiability.

Comment: What if we look at the graph of $x=y^3$?

Comment: We see a function which has a tangent at $x=0$, namely the $y$-axis, but $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: $x=f^{-1}(y)$... there is differentiability in there alright.

Comment: I don't get your point.  The question was “$f$ has a tangent line in $x_0$ $\iff$ $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$,” which simply is not true, namely the $\Rightarrow$-part.

Comment: "A curve in the (unorientated!) plane has a tangent line at $x_0$" $\Leftrightarrow$ "there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that describes the curve and is differentiable at $x_0$". Your point, while correct, is quite narrow and modulo a rotation the equivalence holds, does it not?

Comment: Come on, your'e kidding.  Define what is a “curve” and what is a “function that describes the curve.”  To “have a tangent” is non-trivial: let $c\colon I\to V$ be a curve where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional $R$-vector space; we say that “$c$ hat a tangent in $\tau\in I$” $\iff$ there is a 1-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$ and $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for all $s,t\in I\cap ]\tau-\epsilon,\tau+\epsilon[$ it holds for $s\leq\tau\leq t$ and $s\neq t$ that $$c(s)\neq c(t) \text{ and } \lim_{s,t\to\tau}R\cdot\bigl(c(t)-c(s)\bigr)=W.$$ In that precise sense $c(t):=t^{1/3}$, $R\to R$ has no tangent in $t=0$.

Comment: If your definition is isometry invariant, it has to give the same answer for $y=x^3$ and $x=y^3$ at $(0,0)$.  Does it?

Comment: @zyx Surely not. We are talking about *functions*, not *relations*.

Comment: Does it give the same answer for the two relations?  If yes, then the only problem is the artificial exclusion of $\infty$ as a value of $f'$ when deciding what is the notion of "differentiable" that is equivalent to having a tangent line.

Comment: @zyx Are you capable in reading and applying definitons?  (Well, I sort of doubt about this.). According to the definition I've given $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ has a tangent line in $x=0$, but is not differentiable at $x=0$. Period.  In case you have another definition of “a function possesses a tangent line in $x_0$”, be so kind to let me know your definition, please, and I'll consider to  further discuss this item.  Otherwise I'm tired about that subject.

Comment: I've mistyped sth. in my post of the definition of a tangent line.  The last sentence should read: “ $c$ has a tangent line in $t=0$, but is not differentiable in $t=0$.

Comment: You wrote that "$c(t)=t^{1/3}$ has no tangent in $t=0$".  I was surprised to read that and noticed a contradiction with your definition (which is not standard).  It was not clear if you meant to make a different definition, a different statement about the tangent line existing, or both.  Please explain what power of "reading and applying definitions" would have helped read your mind here.  By the way, most of the world considers $y = |x|^{1/3}$, to have a tangent line at $(0,0)$.  Your definition forbids that.